# Load an external Javascript library in a Lightning Community

Tags: lightning, javascript, community

To add external Javascript library to a Lightning Community, we tried including it in HTML head markup options. Result: CORS errors. We have added the URL to a list of trusted sites but it did not help.

We then tried adding the Javascript library as a static resource and use it in a Lightning component via `ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.ResourceName}"`. The library did load but we weren't able to use it.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. `ltng:require` should work but few scripts which do not use `use strict` will not load. Showing relevant code in question would help us answering better.

Comment: Hi salesforce-sas,

Thanks for your prompt response :)

We have tried to use "use strict" as well, but not working, below are some sample code snippet of js file we trying to use after completion of script. 

$(document).ready(function() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Testing by mohit and rajat");
  var html = $(document).find('#testingcontent').html();
  $(document).find('.searchRegion').append(html);
  console.log("HTML", html); 
 }, 5000);

 console.log("CONTENT", $(document).find('.knowledgebase-menu').html());
});

Comment: when we add in our lightning component , It display the console log after scripts loaded. but It says "undefined" in that log : console.log("HTML", html);  It means, It is not reading the html.

Code written in Lightning component : 
<ltng:require 
                  styles="{!$Resource.CustomCSS}"
                  scripts="{!$Resource.GoogleJQuery}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.getValue}"/>

Below is fire after scripts loaded.

GoogleJQuery:12 CONTENT undefined
GoogleJQuery:6 Testing by mohit and rajat
GoogleJQuery:9 HTML undefined

Answer (score 1):

**added based on comments**

You should not use direct `#` (Id selector) and `.` (class selector) selectors in jquery (or any other library) as that will cross the component boundary. You should instead use `$(component.find('initid').getElement())` which will respect component boundary.

Once the library is loaded `$` is available throughout. Also there is no need of `onready` as you are already invoking the function on `afterScriptsLoaded`.

Below is the sample script:

COMPONENT:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.myscripts +'/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'}"
                       afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />

<div>
    POC test jquery
</div>

<div aura:id="initid" class="initid">
    initid
</div>

<lightning:button label="Add Text" onclick="{!c.addText}" />
<div aura:id="dynamictext" class="dynamictext">
    dynamictext
</div>
```

CONTROLLER js:

```
scriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log('handle scriptsLoaded load => ', $, jQuery);
    $(component.find('initid').getElement()).text('Added text during init');
},
addText : function(component, event, helper){
    $(component.find('dynamictext').getElement()).text('dynamic text from button');
}
```

---

**Old answer**

I just tested in my org with below code:

COMPONENT file:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.myscripts +'/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'}"
                       afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />

<div>
    POC test jquery
</div>
```

CONTROLLER js:

```
scriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log('handle scriptsLoaded load => ', $, jQuery);
}
```

And got below log:

```
handle scriptsLoaded load =>  ƒ (e,t){return new k.fn.init(e,t)} ƒ (e,t){return new k.fn.init(e,t)}
```

This means it is working in **community** - even when I login as community user.

Comment: Hi salesforce-sas,

Sir appreciate your effort :) Just want to say, we are able to get the log which you mentioned sir. It means (we are able to load but reading the HTML is not working means It says "Undefined"

Can you pls add the below code snippet in your JS File (stored in static resource).

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { setTimeout(function() { console.log("Testing by mohit and rajat"); var html = $(document).find('#testingcontent').html(); $(document).find('.searchRegion').append(html); console.log("HTML", html); }, 5000); console.log("CONTENT", $(document).find('.knowledgebase-menu').html()); });

Getting below results in our component controller after scripts loaded.

I fire after scripts loaded.  ƒ (e,t){return new k.fn.init(e,t)} ƒ (e,t){return new k.fn.init(e,t)}
GoogleJQuery:12 CONTENT undefined
GoogleJQuery:6 Testing by mohit and rajat
GoogleJQuery:9 HTML undefined

Comment: In Controller.JS

Written below code :

({
 getValue : function(component, event, helper) {
  console.log('I fire after scripts loaded. ', $, jQuery);
 }
})

Comment: added answer...

Comment: @Rajat is your issue solved?

Comment: Hi salesforce-sas,

Hope you are doing great :) No actually Issue not solved . Thanks for your suggestion, but in your case, the HTML code is added in the component itself with custom attribute, example,
<div aura:id="initid" class="initid">

But in our case, the HTML is dynamically loaded from other components and we do not have control over those components. Hence, the solution will not support our case.

We need a way to read the dynamically added HTML elements from different components like Search Box, Recent Topics, etc. from a custom component that we created.

thanks

Comment: Hi @salesforce-sas, Did you get chance to look the above issues ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @salesforce-sas, 

I know you're busy, just following up if we are able to get clue about resolve the issue .

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code sample with full flow so that I can reproduce in my org

Comment: Sir can you give me skypeId, so that we will connect there and discuss while screen share ?

Comment: Cannot really connect on Skype now, restrictions in office :) you can add code in question, will check that after some time

Comment: Hi @salesforce-sas,

No problem :) Pls use this link : https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js 

It stores Jquery files and we want to read in Lightning community. Can you please help us in that.

We have two approach 
a. Header Markup (Not working for us, we have tried, It says COSP error
b. Lightning Component (Not able to read)

Thanks

Comment: Hi @salesforce-sas,

Sir any doubt in requirement, Pls let me know

Comment: How is the HTML dynamically added... can you create new question with sample code which community members will be able to reproduce? so that me or anybody else will have better solution?